# YUM: How to see what an RPM requires, and presence of prereqs on system without inet

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

Using yum on CentOS 6.8 and 7

System lacks outbound connectivity, for security. We push the needed rpms to the system via sftp.

Questions:

1. If a prereq is missing , and we do yum localinstall, will the install fail?
2. How can we see, before running install, if the install will succeed?

fwiw, we are installing jre 8 and elasticsearch 5.4.

Comment: `jre8` : Depends on glibc. No issues unless glibc / the OS is too old. `elasticsearch` is text + files.jar : No dependencies. Testing for dependencies : `yum install ./[package].rpm` → missing dependencies will be listed. ( `yum localinstall` is with older OS / older yum. CentOS 6, 7 : It's plain `yum install` ).

Answer (score 0):

> If a prereq is missing , and we do yum localinstall, will the install fail?

Yes.

> How can we see, before running install, if the install will succeed?

Run with `--assumeno` and it will not proceed with installation, yum will just check all deps. And I guess it returns different exit code (I did not tried).